# jQuery - Dynamic file input not being styled when adding a new file input

Tags: jquery, html

I have a page that is styling a file input through javascript.

This bit works perfect.

I have just recently added new code to dynamically add a new file input box when a user clicks a href link the code i have used is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){

    $("a:[id=createNew]").bind("click",function(){

            var CounterLimit = 10;
            var LastDivId = $("div:[id=FileUploadDiv]:last").attr("DivValue");
            var appandingDiv = $("div:[id=FileUploadDiv][DivValue="+LastDivId+"]");
            var NewDivId = eval(LastDivId)+1;
            if(CounterLimit>NewDivId){
            var NewUploadDiv = "<div class='text text-auto-height hasFloat' id='FileUploadDiv' DivValue='"+NewDivId+"' style='display: none'><label for='image'>&nbsp;&nbsp;</label><div class='file-input-holder hasFloat'><input type='file' name='filename"+NewDivId+"' id='filename' /></div></div>";
            var UploadDivCounter =eval($("#counter").val())+1;
            $("#counter").val(UploadDivCounter);
            $(NewUploadDiv).show().clone().appendTo(appandingDiv);

        }
        else
        {
            var AlertMessage= "You can upload a maximum of "+CounterLimit+" pics!";
            alert(AlertMessage);
        }
    return false;
    });

});

</script>
```

The code works fine, but the problem is that its adding a default looking file input field instead of the styled one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Comment: Every time you add new <div> with "FileUploadDiv" as it's ID! So you'll end up with couple of Divs with same IDs. First this needs to be fixed by changing id to class or any other way. Depends to your logic. Also if you style your upload button based on ID, then it could not work and you may face this issue. I hope this helps but otherwise I really recommend you to use JsFiddle to simulate the issue and we'll be able to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your css selector for `<input type = "file" />`.